# Evaluate as much of an integral as possible

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider the integrand

$\qquad \cos(x+\sin^{-1}(x)) = \sqrt{1-x^2} \cos(x) - x \sin(x)$

If I ask *Mathematica* to integrate $\cos(x+\sin^{-1}(x))$, *Mathematica* is unable to do so analytically (due to the contribution from $\sqrt{1-x^2} \cos(x)$), however, *Mathematica* is able to evaluate the integral of $x \sin(x)$. Is there any command that instructs *Mathematica* to evaluate an integral as much as it can? That is, if I ask *Mathematica* to compute the integral of $\cos(x+\sin^{-1}(x))$, I want an output that looks like:

$\qquad \int \cos(x+\sin^{-1}(x)) \mathrm dx = \int \sqrt{1-x^2} \cos(x) \mathrm dx -x \cos(x) + \sin(x)$

Such a command would be quite useful with more complicated integrands.

Comment: Your question is quite vague and subjective. In what sense is the right integral "more integrated" than the left one?

Comment: @Berg, sorry for the ambiguity: this was a bit difficult to phrase. The right integral is "more integrated" only in that there is an analytical expression for part of it. Rather than analyzing the entire complicated left integral expression, I can break it into an easy to analyze part plus a complicated (but hopefully less so) part.

Comment: A problem I see is that I don't think this can have a unique answer. A trivial example of what I mean would be something like adding 1 to the integrand on the right hand side and subtracting $x$ from the integrated function. There are all kinds of ways you can split the integrand up, and it will rarely be obvious what is the correct way to split it up.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I agree with march. _Mathematica_  would have to be an artificial intelligence with a sense of mathematical esthetics to do what you ask for. And even then you would probably quarrel with over the choices it made.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are no possible answers to this question.

Comment: *Mathematica* is not yet sufficiently smart to perform such a split. You will have to do some of the analytical legwork yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_] = Cos[x + ArcSin[x]];

Integrate[#, x] & /@ (f[x] // TrigExpand)
```

[image]